# What can I do to mix operations ? with vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a simple calculator that implements a sum, rest, multiplication, and division.

I would like to take the inner text inside of any button with the class "number" to use it later like a number to pass through a function that does the math.

These are the functions to work with the calculator.

```js
const add = (num1, num2) => {
  return num1 + num2;
};

const subtract = (num1, num2) => {
  return num1 - num2;
};

const multiply = (num1, num2) => {
  return num1 * num2;
};

const divide = (num1, num2) => {
  return num1 / num2;
};
 
// Our Buttons
const outPut = document.getElementById('output');
const num = document.getElementsByClassName('number');

const addBtn = document.querySelector('.addOperator');
const subtractBtn = document.querySelector('.subtractOperator');
const multiplyBtn = document.querySelector('.multiplyOperator');
const divideBtn = document.querySelector('.divideOperator');

const allClear = document.querySelector('.ac');

const equals = document.querySelector('.equals');


let plusFirsValue = '';
let secondValue = 0;
let subFirstValue = 0;
let multFirstValue = 0;
let divFirstValue = 0;

for(let i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
  num[i].addEventListener('click', () => { 
    outPut.innerText += num[i].innerText;
    console.log(outPut.innerText);
  });
};

addBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  plusFirsValue = Number(outPut.innerText);
  outPut.innerText = '';
  console.log(plusFirsValue);
});
  
subtractBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  subFirstValue = Number(outPut.innerText);
  outPut.innerText = '';
  console.log(plusFirsValue);
});

multiplyBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  multFirstValue = Number(outPut.innerText);
    outPut.innerText = '';
});

divideBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  divFirstValue = Number(outPut.innerText);
    outPut.innerText = '';
});

equals.addEventListener('click', () => {
  secondValue = Number(outPut.innerText);
  if (plusFirsValue && secondValue) {
    outPut.innerText = add(plusFirsValue, secondValue);
    console.log(add(plusFirsValue, secondValue));
  } else if (subFirstValue && secondValue) {
    outPut.innerText = subtract(subFirstValue, secondValue);
    console.log(subtract(subFirstValue, secondValue));
  } else if (multFirstValue && secondValue) {
    outPut.innerText = multiply(multFirstValue, secondValue);
    console.log(multiply(multFirstValue, secondValue));
  } else if (divFirstValue && secondValue) {
    outPut.innerText = divide(divFirstValue, secondValue);
    console.log(divide(divFirstValue, secondValue));
  }
});

allClear.addEventListener('click', () => {
  outPut.innerText = '';
})
```

```html
  <div id="calculator-grid">
    <div id="output"></div> 

    <button class="ac">AC</button>
    <button class="sun">Sun</button>
    <button class="divideOperator">÷</button>
    <button class="number">7</button>
    <button class="number">8</button>
    <button class="number">9</button>
    <button class="multiplyOperator">*</button>
    <button class="number">4</button>
    <button class="number">5</button>
    <button class="number">6</button>
    <button class="addOperator">+</button>
    <button class="number">1</button>
    <button class="number">2</button>
    <button class="number">3</button>
    <button class="subtractOperator">-</button>
    <button class="number">0</button>
    <button class="number">.</button>
    <button class="equals">=</button>
  </div>
```

Some of the implementation I would like to do is a mix between operations that means, after a sum between 2 numbers I want to rest other. For example 3 + 3 = 6 but then 6 - 3 = 3 in the same operation. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that in your code the first selector (of button with class of 'number') you assign an array with less members than the second selector (where you select ALL the buttons) however in the loop you using the index of numbers.

```
const btn = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
const inp = document.getElementById('output');
for (let i = 0; i < btn.length; ++i) {
  btn[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
  inp.innerText += btn[i].innerText;
});
```

Event listeners added to all of the button and the innerText of the div with id of 'output' is modified by clicking one of the buttons.